# Notepad++ replace with double quote character

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

i have a sample case, in a schema database file let say "demo.sql". inside of this file there are so many SQL syntax to create table, and i need to find :
tableA_1
tableB_1
tableC_1

and replace all those words using "" (double quote) charachter :
"tableA_1"
"tableB_1"
"tableC_1"

i don't understand how to use regular expression to handle this case, due to many SQL schema that i need to assess, anyone has experience for this ? i'll be glad to

Comment: To be clear, you want to add quote **only** to these 3 tablenames? Not any other ones?

Answer (score 0):

This will add quote **only** for tablenames `tableA_1` and `tableB_1` and `tableC_1`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\btable[ABC]_1\b`
- Replace with: `"$0"`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          # word boundary, make sure there're no word character before
table       # literally table
[ABC]       # character class, A or B or C
_1          # literally _1
\b          # word boundary, make sure there're no word character after
```

**Replacement:**

```
"       # a double quote
$0      # the whole match
"       # a double quote
```